# Troubles with executions of automation tests with Test Explorer in Visual Studio and MSTest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, mstest, bdd

I use in my project SpecFlow to provide automation testing of web-site(with Selenium). I want create end-to-end test suite for provide full checking of project according to BDD. When I create tests playlist in test explorer in Visual Studio and start all tests in playlist all my tests launch according to their alphabetic name. But when I restart project and start this playlist newly all my tests launch in the wrong order. I think, that this problem may be because of rebuild playlist file, but I'm not sure. Could You help me, please? 
TestRunner - MSTest

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: no, I don't solve it yet